# PHP Youtube Data Api upload from another domain

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api

I followed the google api examples for uploading to youtube. However if i want to upload a file that hosted on another domain for example:

```
$myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

// create a new Zend_Gdata_App_MediaFileSource object
$filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource('http://www.myotherdomain.com/.../file.mov');
$filesource->setContentType('video/x-flv');

// set slug header
$filesource->setSlug('http://www.myotherdomain.com/.../file.mov');

// add the filesource to the video entry
$myVideoEntry->setMediaSource($filesource);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The Zend API probably doesn't support this. However, if you have write-permissions, you can download the file on your server and then send it.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.myotherdomain.com/.../file.mov');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$contents = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$file = fopen('temp/file.mov', 'w'); // If file is not found, attempts to create it
fwrite($file, $contents);
fclose($file);

// Upload via YouTube
```